# How to start Kafka listener manually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have some methods annotated with `@KafkaListener` but I want to start only some of them manually (depending on some conditions).

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "consumer1", topics = "topic-name", clientIdPrefix = "client-prefix", autoStartup = "false")
public void consumer1(String message) {
    // consume
}
```

```java
@PostConstruct
private void startConsumers() {
    if (true) {
        kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("consumer1").start();
    }
}
```

But at this moment `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()` is empty list and `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("consumer1")` returns `null`. So maybe the moment when `@PostConstruct` method is called is too early and listeners are still not registered.
I tried to annotate `startConsumers()` method with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100)` and listeners are already available. But using `@Scheduled` is not a good decision for something that I want to call once after starting the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do it in `@PostConstruct` - it's too early in the application context life cycle.

Implement `SmartLifecyle` set the phase to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and start the container in the `start()` method.

Or use an `@EventListener` and listen for the `ApplicationStartedEvent` (if using Spring Boot) or `ContextRefreshedEvent` for a non-Boot Spring application.

Comment: ```@EventListener public void onAppStarted(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {}``` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!